# How do I speed up Javascript event handlers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, fullcalendar

I implemented a list of courses so that when a course name is hovered over, the corresponding dates on the calendar are highlighted.

Javascript parses the dates when it is loaded and stores it with the DOM element, so that on `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`, JQuery highlights or removes the highlighting of the corresponding table cells in the calendar.

However, the page takes 8 seconds for the list of courses and the calendar to load and another 1 second to highlight or remove the highlighting of the table cells. `coursesLoaded` is when the course list finishes loading.

```
(function($) {
    $(window).load(function() {
        if ($('.calendar').length) {
            var calendarOs = [];
            $('.calendar').each(function(i, v){
                $(this).html('');
                $(this).prev().hide();
                var calendar = $(this);
                calendar.attr('index', i);
                calendarO = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendar[0], {
                    plugins: [ 'dayGrid' ],
                    defaultView: 'dayGridMonth',
                    header: {
                      left:   '',
                      center: 'title',
                      right:  ''
                    },
                    titleFormat: {
                        year: 'numeric',
                        month: 'long'
                    },
                    themeSystem: 'bootstrap',
                    fixedWeekCount: true,
                    contentHeight: "auto",
                    navLinks: false,
                    eventRender: function(event, eventElement) {
                        eventElement.addClass('calendar');
                    },
                    validRange: function(currentDate) {
                        return {
                          start: new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(), currentDate.getMonth(), 1),
                          // end: new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(), currentDate.getMonth() + 4, 0)
                        };
                    }
                });
                calendarO.render();
                calendarOs.push(calendarO);                
            });

            var year = new Date().getFullYear();
            var date, location, color, array, td;
            //make update only one color
            var updateColors = function(index) {
                var calendar = $(`.calendar[index='${index}']`);
                var calendarO = calendarOs[index];
                var month = calendarO.getDate().getMonth();
                var datesO = JSON.parse(calendar.attr('dates'));
                calendar.find('td.richmond, td.burnaby').removeClass('richmond burnaby');
                var traverseDates = (month == 0) ? [11, 0, 1] : ((month == 11) ? [10, 11, 0] : [month - 1, month, month + 1]);
                traverseDates.forEach(function(month) {
                    datesO[month].forEach(function(obj) {
//                      console.log(obj)
                        calendar.find(`td[data-date=${obj.date}]:not(.fc-day-top)`).addClass(obj.location);
                    });
                });
            }

            $(document).on(`coursesLoaded`, function(e, calendarIndex, dates) {
//                  console.log('coursesLoaded ' + calendarIndex);

                    var calendar = $(`.calendar[index='${calendarIndex}']`);
                    var calendarO = calendarOs[calendarIndex];
                    calendar.attr('dates', JSON.stringify(dates));
                    console.log(calendar.attr('dates'));

                    updateColors(calendarIndex);

                    calendar.parent().prev().find('ul.courses-list li a').hover(function(e){
                        console.log("hovering over: " + performance.now());

                        calendar.find('td.active').removeClass('active');

                        location = $(this).attr('location');
                        array = JSON.parse($(this).attr('dates'));
                        calendarO.gotoDate(array[0]);
                        updateColors(calendarIndex);

                        if (e.type == 'mouseenter') {
                            array.forEach(function(element) {
                                calendar.find(`td[data-date=${element}]:not(.fc-day-top)`).addClass('active');
                            });
                        }

                        console.log("done hovering: " + performance.now());
                    });
                });
        };
        $(document).trigger('doneCalendars');
    });
})(jQuery)
```

Here is the website: http://ess.ccmcanada.org/certified-training/

Comment: Cool effect. You do have the css transition property set, but aside from that It's basically that you're iterating over and changing the DOM piecemeal. Think of the page as a room and your elements are individual lights. Right now you're going through and changing each light from on to off one by one. No matter how quick you do it, it's going to take time. A better way is to use a master switch. Basically, instead of altering the calendar DOM node by node, transplant the new calendar DOM all at once.

Comment: @zfrisch Thanks for the quick response. I considered that but I couldn't quite figure out how to implement that. Would you make a single event handler in that case then? Can you elaborate a bit or provide an example of what you mean?

Comment: https://codepen.io/zfrisch/pen/NWKRgjX    -- the first "piece meal" example iterates, the second "master" example replaces the node in the DOM all at once. Check the console for the times for the operations.

Comment: Keep in mind that this is a single operation for both of these example types. If you combine this with multiple operations the difference between timing becomes even more vast.